# How can I create an override for standard Hex encoding to use my own values?

Tags: c#, encoding, hex, overriding, byte

In standard ASCII hex encoding, we have (char, hex):

```
A 41
B 42
C 43
a 61
b 62
c 63
```

I want to create an override, something like

```cs
CustomHex : Encoding
```

in order to allow a conversion to custom values, for example:

```
A BB
B BC
C BD
a D5
b D6
c D7
```

As it is not a 1:1 shift, I cannot simply use an offset. I've tried using something along the lines of

```cs
public override byte[] GetByte(string s)
```

but so far have not been successful.

Comment: Have you try to use `Dictionary<char, byte>` ?

Comment: Maybe an extension method of `char.ToString()`?

Comment: if it shall be two way, in other words a real encoding, deriving from Encoding is the right thing... can you provide a ruleset for your encoding?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 Encoding key can be found here: https://pastebin.com/raw/30EmpWND

Comment: how is that supposed to be read? for example B1=[""] ... does that mean the string litteral "[\"\"]" is to be encoded B1 ?

Comment: It's an ASCII representation of what the encoded character looks like, inside of brackets. For example, the one that says [pk] and [mn] both are only one character.